# How to Import coupon code csv in magento

Tags: magento, csv

> I want to **import coupon code csv** in magento.

i have a csv but can't have any knowledge about how to import it. i googled it but didn't  get any proper solution.

Please suggest, How i **import coupon code csv** in magento

Comment: you mean, add promotions shopping cart rule by csv?

Comment: @DRAJi, yes add promotion shopping cart rule.

Comment: if your issues still not resolve you can check this extension of [magento 2 import coupon codes](https://www.mageants.com/import-coupon-codes-for-magento-2.html) hopefully it will solve

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before in Magento 2 using just admin and MySQL. 
You need access to admin and the database, and a text editor with regex find and replace (eg Notepad++)
This process would be similar in Magento 1.

1. Create the coupon on Magento 2 Admin :: Marketing > Cart Price Rules > Add (or duplicate) rule. Set all the rule parameters and tick "Use Auto-generation". Save and Continue Edit.
2. Manage coupon codes. Set the parameters as per the coupons you want to import. Generate 1 coupon.
3. Look in M2 database table salesrule_coupon for the one you just generated - eg: `SELECT * FROM salesrule_coupon WHERE CODE = '[replace with generated code]'`
4. Export the row as an SQL insert, with headers, but no auto_increment column (or just change the rule_id (eg `1999`) and created_at datetime in the “replace” statement below.
5. Paste the coupons into Notepad++, convert them into insert statements.

Handy Notepad++ regex for this:

Coupon data example:

```
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
```

Find

```
(.*)
```

Replace (In Notepad++ you'll need to escape brackets with backslashes - )

```
INSERT INTO `salesrule_coupon` \(`rule_id`, `code`, `usage_limit`, `usage_per_customer`, `times_used`, `expiration_date`, `is_primary`, `created_at`, `type`, `generated_by_dotmailer`\) VALUES \(1999, '$1', 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, '2019-09-06 05:08:48', 1, NULL\);
```

Then run that against the database and refresh the rule in the admin screen - your new coupons will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is a bit older the above answer can also solved via this source. Here a CSV is imported using a fixed percentage. The CSV is given as an example too. Hope this helps!

http://www.livesyncshop.com/tutorials/how-to-import-multiple-coupons-in-magento-from-a-csv/

```
is_active,coupon_code,description,discount_amount
1,1c5e8b24,serie1 coupon,20
1,593d90a1,serie1 coupon,20
```

Now paste this code into a php file

```
<?php

// Import coupon codes
// Thanks go out to Marius Strajeru
// Original URL: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.nl/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html
// modified to use fixed percentage and one time use

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// Import CSV from ViArt format:
$handle = fopen('all_coupons1.csv', 'r');
$cols   = array_flip(fgetcsv($handle));

while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
{

    if($data[$cols['is_active']] == 1)
    {
        echo 'Importing coupon with code: '.$data[$cols['coupon_code']].'<br />';
        createCoupon(
            $data[$cols['coupon_code']],
            $data[$cols['description']],
            'by_fixed',
            $data[$cols['discount_amount']]
        );
    } else {
        echo 'Not imported (not active): '.$data[$cols['coupon_code']].'<br />';
    }
}

/**
* Import coupon
* @param $code             String  Coupon code
* @param $description      String  Description
* @param $type             String  by_percent, by_fixed, cart_fixed, buy_x_get_y (not implemented)
* @param $amount           int     The amount
* @param array $options    Optional options (from, to)
*/
function createCoupon($code, $description, $type, $amount, $options = array())
{
    // Create coupon:
    /* @var $rule Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule */
    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');

 // set name can be code coupon by using ($code)
    $rule->setName('20procent');
    $rule->setCouponCode($code);
    $rule->setDescription($description);

    // Default options:
    if(!isset($options['from'])) { $options['from'] = date('Y-m-d'); }

    $rule->setFromDate($options['from']); // From date

    // To date:
    if(isset($options['to'])) {
        $rule->setToDate($options['to']);//if you need an expiration date
    }

    $rule->setUsesPerCoupon(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon
    $rule->setUsesPerCustomer(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon for each customer
    $rule->setCustomerGroupIds(getAllCustomerGroups());//if you want only certain groups replace getAllCustomerGroups() with an array of desired ids
    $rule->setIsActive(1);
    $rule->setStopRulesProcessing(0);//set to 1 if you want all other rules after this to not be processed
    $rule->setIsRss(0);//set to 1 if you want this rule to be public in rss
    $rule->setIsAdvanced(1);//have no idea what it means :)
    $rule->setProductIds('');
    $rule->setSortOrder(0);// order in which the rules will be applied

    $rule->setSimpleAction('by_percent');

    $rule->setDiscountAmount($amount);//the discount amount/percent. if SimpleAction is by_percent this value must be <= 100
    $rule->setDiscountQty(0);//Maximum Qty Discount is Applied to
    $rule->setDiscountStep(0);//used for buy_x_get_y; This is X
    $rule->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);//set to 1 for Free shipping
    $rule->setApplyToShipping(1);//set to 0 if you don't want the rule to be applied to shipping
    $rule->setWebsiteIds(getAllWbsites());//if you want only certain websites replace getAllWbsites() with an array of desired ids

    $labels = array();
    $labels[0] = $description;
    $rule->setStoreLabels($labels);

    $rule->setCouponType(2);
    $rule->save();
}

/**
* Get all customer groups
* @return array
*/
function getAllCustomerGroups(){
    //get all customer groups
    $customerGroups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($customerGroups as $group){
        $groups[] = $group->getId();
    }
    return $groups;
}

/**
* Get all websites
* @return array
*/
function getAllWbsites(){
    //get all wabsites
    $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
    $websiteIds = array();
    foreach ($websites as $website){
        $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
    }
    return $websiteIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin go to System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow Advanced Profiles
Click on the “Add New Profile” button
Populate the “Profile Name” and “Action XML” text fields:
Profile Name – write the name you want
Action XML – paste this template:

```html
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[coupons_test.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">100</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">Extendix_CouponImport_Model_SimpleImport</var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

for mor details follow this link

http://ceckoslab.com/magento/free-extension-coupons-import/